# Reboot Windows Mobile 6.x device programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, compact-framework, .net-cf-3.5

My HTC HD2 can't be rebooted from OS, just shut down. So I want to write a small program to do that.

Is it possible to programmatically reboot Windows Mobile 6.x device using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the documented `ExitWindowsEx` API. `IOCTL` should only be used on platforms lacking the ExitWindowsEx function call (Pocket PC 2000, 2002, and 2003).  See the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416523.aspx) for more information.

```
[DllImport("aygshell.dll", SetLastError=""true"")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ExitWindowsEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]uint dwFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]uint dwReserved);

enum ExitWindowsAction : uint
{
    EWX_LOGOFF = 0,
    EWX_SHUTDOWN = 1,
    EWX_REBOOT = 2,
    EWX_FORCE = 4,
    EWX_POWEROFF = 8
}

void rebootDevice()
{
    ExitWindowsEx(ExitWindowsAction.EWX_REBOOT, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! btw, what do you think about `SetSystemPowerState` found here: http://www.krvarma.com/windows-mobile/how-to-soft-reset-windows-mobile-programmatically/

Comment: It seems like a valid replacement for ExitWindowsEx.  SetSystemPowerState is more versatile and is supported on earlier platforms than ExitWindowsEx.  SetSystemPowerState seems like the function to use if you're targeting Windows CE or a mixture of Windows CE & Pocket PC & Windows Mobile devices.

Answer (score 5):

SOFTRESET / HARDRESET

```
public class Reboot
{
    public const uint FILE_DEVICE_HAL = 0x00000101;
    public const uint METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;
    public const uint FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;

    public static uint CTL_CODE(uint DeviceType, uint Function, uint Method, uint Access)
    {
        return ((DeviceType << 16) | (Access << 14) | (Function << 2) | Method);
    }

    [DllImport("Coredll.dll")]
    public extern static uint KernelIoControl
    (
        uint dwIoControlCode,
        IntPtr lpInBuf,
        uint nInBufSize,
        IntPtr lpOutBuf,
        uint nOutBufSize,
        ref uint lpBytesReturned
    );

    /// <summary>
    /// Causes the CE device to soft/warm reset
    /// </summary>
    public static uint SoftReset()
    {
        uint bytesReturned = 0;
        uint IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_HAL, 15, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
        SetCleanRebootFlag();
        return KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned);
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public extern static uint SetSystemPowerState
    (
        String psState,
        Int32 StateFlags,
        Int32 Options
    );

    const int POWER_FORCE = 4096;
    const int POWER_STATE_RESET = 0x00800000;

    public static uint ColdReset()
    {
        SetCleanRebootFlag();
        return SetSystemPowerState(null, POWER_STATE_RESET, POWER_FORCE);
    }

    [DllImport("Coredll.dll")]
    public extern static int KernelIoControl(int dwIoControlCode, IntPtr lpInBuf, int nInBufSize, IntPtr lpOutBuf, int nOutBufSize, ref int lpBytesReturned);

    [DllImport("Coredll.dll")]
    public extern static void SetCleanRebootFlag();

    public static void HardReset()
    {
        int IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT = 0x101003C;
        int bytesReturned = 0;
        SetCleanRebootFlag();
        KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned);
    }


    [DllImport("aygshell.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ExitWindowsEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]uint dwFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]uint dwReserved);

    enum ExitWindowsAction : uint
    {
        EWX_LOGOFF = 0,
        EWX_SHUTDOWN = 1,
        EWX_REBOOT = 2,
        EWX_FORCE = 4,
        EWX_POWEROFF = 8
    }
//
    void rebootDevice()
    {
        ExitWindowsEx(ExitWindowsAction.EWX_REBOOT, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you: [Hard Reset Windows Mobile Device](http://blog.harshvirsidhu.com/programming/hard-reset-windows-mobile-device)..Still this method is not "clear c# code", because it uses Interop, but it works, so it can solve your problem.

For **soft** reset:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool KernelIoControl(int dwIoControlCode, byte[] inBuf, int inBufSize, byte[] outBuf, int outBufSize, ref int bytesReturned);

private const uint FILE_DEVICE_HAL = 0x00000101;
private const uint METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;
private const uint FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;

private static uint CTL_CODE(uint DeviceType, uint Function, uint Method, uint Access)
{
     return ((DeviceType << 16) | (Access << 14) | (Function << 2) | Method);
}

public static void softReset()
{
     uint bytesReturned = 0;
     uint IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_HAL, 15, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
     KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned);
}
```

(tho i haven't used this method myself..see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/51e09510-3d6e-42a6-bec0-a68ef9d7b947))

Comment: I need to do soft reset, i.e. just reboot. Hard reset resets device to defaults