# How to catch device reset events on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce

There are a few ways to reset device programatically:

1. [SetSystemPowerState](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8022427/1058279)
2. [ExitWindowsEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437963/1058279)

But how to catch device event and log some info for debug purpose (like calling process, etc)?

Solution [here](http://www.techlicity.com/blog/dotnetcf-manage-windows-ce-device-power-settings.html#usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try GetSystemPowerState here  ->  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899319.aspx

and here
 http://www.techlicity.com/blog/dotnetcf-manage-windows-ce-device-power-settings.html